# Отправка sms-сообщений windows phone sdk 8.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

Как отправить sms-сообщение через windows phone sdk 8.1?

Comment: В Windows 10 появился API, позволяющий принимать и отправлять sms вообщения.
Вот официальный пример: [SmsSendAndReceive](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SmsSendAndReceive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отправка SMS сообщения из кода WindowsPhone 8.1:

```
var message = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
message.Body = "Тело сообщения";
message.Recipients.Add("+77777777777");
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(message);
```

Comment: А имеется возможность просмотра списка полученных сообщений?

Comment: @Алексей Нет. Политика безопастности не позволяет просматривать сообщения, это не Android

Comment: Windows 10 позволяет делать такие вещи, если я не ошибаюсь)