# отправка сообщений windows phone 8.0

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Решил попрактиковаться с windows phone и начал с отправки сообщений. Нашёл [тутор](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394005(v=vs.105).aspx), но вот беда при вызове метода `Show()` класса `SmsComposeTask` открывается приложение "Сообщения" и там уже пользователь подтверждает отправку СМС-сообщения.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SmsComposeTask sms = new SmsComposeTask();
    sms.To = "+375336961075";
    sms.Body = "Привет";
    sms.Show();
}
```

Существует ли возможность отправки Смс без участия пользователя?

Comment: Странно было бы, если бы метод Show не показывал UI. А какие ещё методы есть у класса `SmsComposeTask`?

Comment: @VladD унаследованные от класса Object

Comment: Да, маловато. :(

Comment: @Алексей я уже давал ответ на ваш вопрос ранее http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465143/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-sms-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-windows-phone-sdk-8-1/465209#465209 Хотелось бы напомнить, WindowsPhone не Android, у него более высокий уровень безопастности, без подтверждения пользователем SMS не отправить. Так же нет возможности SMS читать. Если бы мы имели возможность это все делать, то первое что получили это неконтролируемое количество вирусов на удачной платформе

Comment: @Dmitry суть этого вопроса - в отправке сообщения без участия пользователя, так что это не дубликат, а просто вопрос на который стоит аргументированно ответить "нет"

Comment: @PashaPash согласен, был неправ

Answer (score 1):

Из комментариев:

WindowsPhone не Android, у него более высокий уровень безопастности, без подтверждения пользователем SMS не отправить. Так же нет возможности SMS читать. Если бы мы имели возможность это все делать, то первое что получили это неконтролируемое количество вирусов на удачной платформе.